# Why are existing dependencies being removed during 'pod install' in a React Native project?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

Description of the Problem:
When running pod install --no-repo-update in my React Native project, I observed that certain existing dependencies were removed during the process.

1. Downloading dependencies

- Installing AppAuth 1.6.2 (was 1.4.0)/n
- Installing Firebase 6.34.0
- Installing GTMAppAuth 1.3.1 (was 1.2.2)
- Installing GTMSessionFetcher 1.7.2 (was 1.7.0)
- Installing GoogleUtilities 6.7.2
- Installing Protobuf 3.25.2 (was 3.19.4)
- Installing RNSVG 12.5.1 (was 12.3.0)
- Installing lottie-ios (3.1.9)
- Installing lottie-react-native (3.5.0)
- Installing react-native-camera 3.44.3
- Removing BVLinearGradient
- Removing FirebaseAnalytics
- Removing FirebaseAuth
- Removing FirebaseDynamicLinks
- Removing FirebaseInstanceID
- Removing FirebaseMessaging
- Removing FirebaseStorage
- Removing GoogleAppMeasurement
- Removing RNAppleAuthentication
- Removing RNCAsyncStorage
- Removing RNCMaskedView
- Removing RNCPicker
- Removing RNDateTimePicker
- Removing RNDeviceInfo
- Removing RNFBAnalytics
- Removing RNFBAuth
- Removing RNFBDynamicLinks
- Removing RNFBMessaging
- Removing RNFBStorage
- Removing RNFastImage
- Removing RNReactNativeHapticFeedback
- Removing RNScreens
- Removing SDWebImage
- Removing SDWebImageWebPCoder
- Removing Toast
- Removing libwebp
- Removing react-native-apple-authentication
- Removing react-native-blur
- Removing react-native-geolocation
- Removing react-native-image-picker
- Removing react-native-maps
- Removing react-native-safe-area-context
- Removing react-native-simple-toast
- Removing react-native-slider
- Removing react-native-version-check
- Removing react-native-webview
  Generating Pods project

**Why are existing dependencies being removed during the 'pod install' process?, Is there a way to prevent the removal of specific dependencies?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11486138/mahdi-souilmi see my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831841/6197968, This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to define the exact dependency version.

e.g.

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0'
```

means install the Alamofire having version 5.0 or later. So every time you run pod install it will try to install the latest compatible version.

```
 pod 'Alamofire', '5.0'
```

This means install the exactly the 5.0 version even if new version is available. It will not change the lib version.

```
 pod 'Alamofire'
```

This means install the latest version compatible to your pod version.

**So basically you have to remove ~> sign before the library version number.**

Comment: thank you for Answering, but in my case, i didn’t add anything to the pod file

Comment: If possible can you share you podfile ?

Comment: yeah , you can see it below

Answer (score 0):

```js
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target '' do


rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])


  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'


  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'react-native-viewpager', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/viewpager'

  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

  pod 'ReactNativeGetLocation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-get-location'
  pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [
    'BarcodeDetectorMLKit'
  ]

  target '' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.87.0' , 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3' , 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```